# Cisco Anyconnect on VM not installing

Tags: windows, mac, vpn, virtual-machine

my University requires us to use the in-house VPN to connect to some of the University Infrastructure. The client is Cisco Anyconnect 4.10
Problem is, that the VPN is persistent on my Mac even when the client is killed and turned off. The VPN configurations and tunnels still actively persist in my Mac Network settings.

Since I don't want them to monitor my traffic, I tried to install the VPN client on Win 11 on parallels to have some peace. The client won't even pass the installation part. No logs, no nothing. Parallels is isolated, and I am using the Wi-Fi bridge setup currently. Tried troubleshooting with other configurations, but nothing... I am thinking they are purposefully restricting VM's to push users to just install on their main device. F that. Maybe some sort of anti-VM software?

How should I proceed? How do I configure my VM to be completely standalone?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Which installation files are you using for Anyconnect?

Comment: Custom ones provided

Comment: If provided from in-house, ask for ones that work.